# If constants converge to $f$ uniformly, then f is constant.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n : [a, b] → \Bbb R$ be a sequence of constant functions (that is, for each fixed $n ∈ \Bbb N,\: f(x) = f(y)$ for all $x, y ∈ [a, b]$. Show that if $f_n → f $ uniformly, then $f$ is also a constant function.

So far what I have is that I understand the fact that a constant function means it is continuous but the opposite is not true. As such, I am trying to model my proof that when $f$ converges uniformly on an interval, then f is continuous on the same interval but I am a little unsure on how to use this foundation to prove that $f$ is constant function instead of continuous.

Comment: Pointwise convergence suffices. You don't need uniform.

Comment: A pointwise convergent sequence of constant functions can't fail to also converge uniformly.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff, so a sequence of points can only converge to one point!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$ and take $\varepsilon=\frac12\bigl\lvert f(x_1)-f(x_2)\bigr\rvert$. Then, if $n$ iis large enough, you have$$(\forall x\in[a,b]):\bigl\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\bigr\rvert<\varepsilon.$$But $f_n$ is a constant function $k_n$. So, $\bigl\lvert k_n-f(x_1)\bigr\rvert<\varepsilon$ and $\bigl\lvert k_n-f(x_2)\bigr\rvert<\varepsilon$ and therefore…

Answer (score 1):

For all $x\in [a, b]$ one has
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(a) = f(a)
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

Fix $x_0\in [a,b]$. Then

$$
|f(x_0)-f(x)|\le |f(x_0)-f_n(x_0)|+|f_n(x_0)-f_n(x)|+|f_n(x)-f(x)| 
$$
Clearly $|f_n(x_0)-f_n(x)|=0$, while $|f(x_0)-f_n(x_0)|$ and $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ can become
arbitrarily small, for $n$ sufficiently large, due to the uniform convergence.

Answer (score 0):

Let $c_n = f_{n}(x)$ the sequence of constant functions. Thus, 
$$ |c_n - c_{m}| = |f_n(x) - f_m(x)| \leq \| f_n - f_m \|_{\infty} \rightarrow 0.$$
 Hence, $(c_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, and there exists $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_n c_n = c$. Therefore, 
$$|f(x) - c| \leq |f(x) - f_n(x)| + |f_n(x) - c| \leq \|f_n - f \|_{\infty} + |c_n - c|.$$ So, making $n \rightarrow \infty$, we obtain that $f = c$.

Comment: More like $f_n = c_n.$

Answer (score 0):

As all $f_n$ are constant, nothing depends on $x$ in this question, hence $f_n$ can only be uniformly convergent to a constant $f$.